# For Pinescript v5: Are "input" allowed in user-defined-functions?

Tags: function, input, pine-script, pine-script-v5, user-defined

It seems input() statements are not allowed in user-defined functions.  Why?  Am I overlooking something?  How can I fix it?

I am trying to write a generic user-defined function for inputs, but they seem to be not allowed or are otherwise faulty.  I think "input" are not allowed in functions because all "input" must be at global scope, and cannot be in a local or block scope.

Comment: You want to fix something that is not allowed in the programming language you are using?

Comment: Btw. you can ave `inputs` in functions but I wouldn't recommend to do so. Could you please share your code?